Problem in Unity's navigation system - getting stuck and time-consuming path calculations
I am making a strategy game in Unity.
Everything seems to be going well.
The only problem that has frustrated me is that when the number of armies and soldiers in the game increases, the navigation system does not work properly.
For example, when I want to send 200 soldiers from one location to a new position, the soldiers move one by one towards the target.
It seems that the navigation system cannot find a valid path for this number of soldiers in real-time, and this takes time, leading to the issue.
Now imagine that at the same time, other enemies want to send their armies to new positions.
Naturally, the navigation problem becomes more severe and unbearable.
I have another issue as well.
While the navigation is calculating the paths for the soldiers, the workers in the empire who are working and walking also get stopped and cannot move until the paths for the soldiers are calculated and they move. Then the workers start moving as well.
This problem has really annoyed me.
Please, if anyone has the same issue, like this question so it gets seen, and if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.
I apologize for my poor English.
Thank you.
I haven't found a suitable solution for this issue.
I just set a limit on the number of troops to avoid problems for now.
But this definitely isn't a good solution, and this problem needs to be resolved.
Do you know a similar Android game that can manage a large number of soldiers in a 3D environment in a strategy game?

As i understand the navmesh system is not designed for the likes of 200 soldiers as individuals.  you might do better to group them and have them act as a unit

Thank you for your response. This is a good idea too. I will try it. But I wonder what methods are used in large games like Stronghold Crusader 2 that allow them to move a large number of units so effectively without encountering problems.

Unity DOTS? To example with this library (from this reddit topic)

I had never heard of this package before!! It seems very powerful and interesting, and of course complex! Thank you for introducing it to me. Exactly one of its strengths is my biggest problem and weakness. I'm amazed at how it can move thousands of units without any lag!!

Have you tried to use A* algorithm? I used it a couple years ago and it was calculating the ways dynamicly according to obstacles. I'm not sure about is it the best case for an army size but you can give it a shot.
Also please stop apologizing for your English in every answer and post, you are okay :)

Unity's navmesh pathfinding already uses A*...

No, I have not used this algorithm yet. Unfortunately, I cannot work on my project more than 2 hours a day. But thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely use a* to see if it solves my problem or not. I don't think the problem is with my codes. Because they seem optimal. May I know why you used A* algorithm instead of navigation? The reason for my apologies is that I am translating my comments into English with a translator :)

There is no specific cause actually. I searched for path finding systems and A* was the first result actually.
A* Pathfinding
This was the video that I used

I used the A* algorithm and compared it with Unity's navigation. I navigated about 300 objects using both methods and didn't see any significant difference that would encourage me to use A*. The navigation time was almost the same for both methods, and the game's FPS was also quite similar. Now I need to take some time to try out Unity DOTS. It seems very complex and powerful. I hope I can get good results with it.
